# How do I merge multiple duplicate rows with different column values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to merge multiple varying CSV files. The issue is that when merging all the CSV files, I get multiple duplicate rows with different column values. I'd like to have no duplicate rows and all columns values in that one row.

Here is a visualization of the end result I'm trying to achieve. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZtfT.png),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF4k3.png)

I hope that the questioning format is understandable. Thanks in advance

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0).agg('first')`, assuming the grouping values are your Index and those NULLs get read in as a pandas-recognizable missing value (i.e. `NaN`).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library, which provides a lot of data processing primitives.

Please, let me know if you check the below and it doesn't suit you for some reason:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

files = [
    "tmp/input_1.csv",
    "tmp/input_2.csv",
]
# tables are lazy and only read first header row
table = Table.from_csv(files[0], header=True)
for f in files[1:]:
    table = table.chain(Table.from_csv(f, header=True), fill_value="")

# remember the header
header = table.columns

# prepare converter, which groups by first column and aggregates as many
# columns as columns in the resulting table
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item(0))
    .aggregate(
        [c.item(0)]
        + [
            # consider replacing with c.ReduceFuncs.Last
            c.ReduceFuncs.First(c.item(i), where=c.item(i) != "")
            for i in range(1, len(header))
        ]
    )
    .gen_converter()
)

# aggregation step
processed_rows = converter(table.into_iter_rows(list))
# dropping to disk
Table.from_rows(processed_rows, header=header).into_csv("tmp/out.csv")
```